# How to navigate a mutipart/form-data in Mulesoft 4.2 Dataweave 2.2?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to get grab content out of multipart/form-data in Dataweave 2.2.  I just want to send back the pdf from the second part of the payload.  I am having no luck parsing through this payload using Dataweave.

My dataweave code is simply `payload.parts` and I get the following error.

```
org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "Multipart Object does not have `parts` field defined. Expecting type is
{
  preamble?: String, 
  parts: {
    _*: {
      headers: Object, 
      content: Any
    }
  }
}, while writing MultiPart at payload.parts." evaluating expression: "payload.parts".
```

Here is my payload. I trimmed the xml and file content for readability.

```
--MIMEBoundary_fdb504344c826b00b136f8946dec737661b743b37d6dc8c4
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.cdb504344c826b00b136f8946dec737661b743b37d6dc8c4@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_fdb504344c826b00b136f8946dec737661b743b37d6dc8c4
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <edb504344c826b00b136f8946dec737661b743b37d6dc8c4@apache.org>

%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Smart Communications)
/Producer (Smart Communications)
/CreationDate (D:20200115094841-05'00')
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
  /N 3
  /Length 3 0 R
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x���wXS���sN�`$!l{��@
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is that your expression has no output defined which means DataWeave will try to infer it using the information available. As the `payload` used in the expression is multipart it will infer that format as output but `payload.parts` is not a valid multipart so you get the failure.
Considering your use case, you should probably extract the PDF part directly as binary content:

```
output application/octet-stream
---
payload.parts[1].content
```

Just remember to set the actual PDF mime type (I'm assuming you are using a `set-payload`)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by set the actual PDF mime type?  Where do I do that?  I wasn't using a set payload.  I am using a transform message and setting the payload that way.   Same thing, right?

Comment: I mean if you use a `set-payload` instead you will be able to set the mime type on it to `application/pdf` so it's transmitted/store with that mime type wherever you want to send/write it to.

Comment: I am now using set-payload where I can set the MIME type to application/pdf and that is working now.